# scaling flask app on AWS ECS with nginx and uwsgi

Tags: flask, uwsgi, amazon-ecs

I am trying to scale a flask micro service in AWS ECS to handle production workloads. My application is using the flask-apschedueler to handle long running tasks. I am using uwsgi web server for deployment in ECS so I am packing the application inside the container along with uwsgi server. The nginx container is running separately on ECS cluster.

My uwsgi config uses a single process, single thread right now.

I have successfully deployed it on AWS ECS but wondering what to scale for handling production workloads. I am debating between these options

1) I can spin up multiple containers and nginx would round robin to all of them distributing requests equally through route 53 dns service

2) I can increase the number of processes in uwsgi config but that messes with my flask-apscheduler as I only need one instance of it running. The workarounds I found are not that neat

It would be great if someone can share how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker mentality is more along the lines of 'one process per task'. Anytime you have more than one task running on a container, you should rethink.

I would advise the first approach. Create a service to wrap your task in ECS and simply vary the 'Desired' number of tasks for that service to scale the service up and down as desired.

If you only need the scheduler running on one of the tasks, you should setup a separate service using the same image, but with an environment variable to tell your container to start the scheduler. Make it true on the scheduler service/task and false on the worker service/tasks. Those ENV variables can be set on the container definition inside your ECS task definition.

This would be the "docker way".